Prove that the canonical mapping from an infinite dimensional vector space to it's double dual is a one-to-one mapping.
What is the canonical correspondence from a vector space V to it's double dual $V^{**}.$ Prove that this correspondence is one-one.($V$ need not be finite dimensional)
I tried solving the problem in the following way:
Let $V $ be a vector space over $F.$ For any $v\in V$ we define a mapping $\hat v:V^*\to F$ such that $\hat v(f)=f(v),\forall f\in V^*.$
We define $\psi:V\to V^{**}$ such that $\psi(v)=\hat v,\forall v\in V.$ This mapping $\psi$ is the canonical correspondence from a vector space $V$ to it's double dual $V^{**}.$
We need to show that $\psi$ is a one-one linear transformation.
Let $v_1,v_2\in V$ and $c\in F.$
We note that, $\psi(v_1+v_2)=\widehat {v_1+v_2}=\hat v_1+\hat v_2=\psi(v_1)+\psi(v_2)$
$\big(,$ since $\forall f\in V^*$ we have, $$(\widehat{v_1+v_2})(f)=f(v_1+v_2)=f(v_1)+f(v_2)=\hat v_1(f)+\hat v_2(f)=(\hat v_1+\hat v_2)(f)\implies \widehat {v_1+v_2}=\hat v_1+\hat v_2\big).$$
Again, by a similar type of argument, we have $\psi(cv_1)=c\psi(v_1).$
This proves $\psi$ is a linear transformation.
If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space then $\psi$ is an isomorphism.
I proved this using the lemma:

However, I don't understand how to prove that $\psi$ is still a one-one mapping if $V$ is not finite dimensional vector space. Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated.

Why the downvote?

Startng point: Let $x$ be in the kernel of $\psi$.

@geetha290krm Yes and? I can only say, that $f(x)=0,\forall f\in V^*.$ But then what?

Hint: that would violate Hahn-Banach.

@TheoBendit Sorry, but I don't what Hahn-Banach is about...

I might have been reading into your question a functional analysis bent. Just to clarify: the duals in question are algebraic duals, right? That is, the set of all linear functionals (regardless of any topological considerations)? Hahn-Banach usually pertains to topological duals (although an even simpler version of it works for algebraic duals).

@TheoBendit Yes

How do you prove that $\psi$ is injective in the finite dimensional case?

@geetha290krm Well, there is a theorem which states that if $x\in V$ be such that $\hat x(f)=0,\forall f\in V^*$ then $x=0$ provided that $V$ is finite dimensional. Using this I proved that $\psi$ is injective.

I don't think that proof requires finite dimensionality. Can you quote that proof here?

@geetha290krm I have attached the proof in the original post.

@geetha290krm Using the construction of $f$ as you mentioned we can say, if $x\neq x_2$ and $\psi(x)=\hat x=\psi(x_2)=\hat x_2$ holds then,$\hat x(f)=\hat x_2(f)= 0=1,$ a contradiction, due to which we can say, $\psi$ is one-to-one. But I don't know axiom of choice as of yet, so can you please specify that why such a functional $f$ always exist in case of any vector space?

Do you know Zorn's lemma? Or at least, are you aware that every (possibly infinite-dimensional) vector space has a Hamel basis?

@TheoBendit I'm sorry but they are not even mentioned in our course :?)

Then, at the moment, this may be beyond your ken. I'm pretty sure that the axiom of choice, or some weaker form, is necessary to prove this theorem.

@TheoBendit Sorry I got confused by the term, 'Hamel basis'. I googled it and I found out that the basis of an infinite dimensional vector space is called a Hamel basis. So, yes, I am aware of the result that every vector space has a basis. But, I haven't heard of Zorn's lemma till now.

Let $\psi: V \to V^{**}$ be the canonical injection $v\mapsto (g \mapsto g(v))$, we want to prove that $\psi$ is injective. If we have some non-zero $v\in V$ we can extend $\{v\}$ to a basis of $V$ and define a linear functional $g: V \to F$ by letting $g(v)=1$ and $g(x)=0$ for all other vectors $x$ in the basis, and then extending by linearity. Then $\psi(v)(g)=g(v)=1$ so $\psi(v)\neq 0$, showing that there can't be a non-zero vector $v$ such that $\psi(v)=0$, which implies that $\psi$ is injective.
Note that this is essentially the same as the proof you posted for the finite-dimensional case, the dimension being infinite doesn't make a big difference for the injectivity (but this map $\psi$ will also be surjective if and only if $V$ is finite-dimensional).

Just to clarify: The proof I posted for the finite dimensional case uses a lemma that I attached as a picture in the original post. But that lemma is not valid if V is infinite-dimensional right? So, how is this similar to the proof I posted for the finite dimensional case?

@ThomasFinley I was referring to the proof of the lemma (but I see now that I did not make that very clear).

Ok, but my question still remains the same. It would be very helpful if you consider making it clear.

@ThomasFinley I wrote a proof above, which part would you like me to elaborate on?
